# Django admin and column width through list_display

Tags: django, django-admin

I read in  Django >= 1.6 docs:

> "The field names in list_display will also appear as CSS classes in
>   the HTML output, in the form of column- on each 
>   element. This can be used to set column widths in a CSS file."

OK. But, how?

```
class bollaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  ordering = ['num']
  list_display = ('num|width=15', 'Vendemmia','Cultivar', 'Provenienza' , 'netto', 'grado','montegradi')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a snippet of HTML for the column containing the attribute `headline` from one of my admins:

```
<th scope="col" class="sortable column-headline">
   <div class="text"><a href="?o=2.4.-5">Headline</a></div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</th>
```

You could set the width of that in CSS like this:

```
th.column-headline {
  width: 10000000px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there no way to do that through admin.py code, without modifying css?

Comment: No, there isn't a way to do it through the admin.py code. It's good practice to do styling in CSS, separate from the python code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the lazy person's method to extend a column width in the django admin without doing a css override.

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def get_column_extended_field(self, obj):
        result = ''
        field_value = obj.field_value
        if field_value:
            spaces = '&nbsp;' * 75
            result = format_html('{result}<br/>' + spaces, result=field_value)
        return result
    get_column_extended_field.short_description = _('Extended Field')
```